# Firebase Test Lab does not launch Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-test-lab

A basic Flutter app failed to launch on Firebase Test Lab for Android.  I can see in the video that the app never came up so it never even tried running my tests, it just timed out.  In the logs, I do not see any errors from my application; there are errors and warnings but I can't understand any of them nor do I know if they're ok to ignore.  I used Firebase Test Lab on other projects and I'm accustomed to seeing lots of errors which I assume come from Firebase Test Lab's infrastructure.  I typically look through the errors to try to find something that might pertain to my app.  In this case I don't see anything that seems to be related to my app.

The app is from the code lab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#0 .

The instructions for Firebase setup are at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#firebase-test-lab .

The test passes when run locally by running the following command on my Mac:

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Ptarget=`pwd`/../integration_test/app_test.dart
```

The command I run from my CI (gitlab) is as follows:

```
gcloud firebase test android run --type instrumentation --app build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --test build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
```

I got the same timeout by initiating the test through the Firebase Test Lab UI.

I also posted this question at https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1MTSQ5QT/p1674438388007639 .

Any ideas for what I could investigate?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Firebase Test Lab to test a Flutter App by using this Espresso "bridge" https://pub.dev/packages/espresso.  So instead of writing Flutter tests with the `integrationDriver` from package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart as described in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#driver-entrypoint, I can use the `enableFlutterDriverExtension()` from package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart .

Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I eventually tracked it down to my various `AndroidManfiest.xml` files, where I hadn't updated the `package` attribute.

ie. I had in my `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.myapp">
 ...
```

instead of

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.myreal.package">
```